# Redirect output of shell script to a file

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm trying to redirect the output of my script and it needs to be called inside the script.

```
filename=uname -a
filename="$filename" date

2>&1 | tee $filename".txt"
```

That is what I have so far, but it's obviously wrong. I don't know too much SH scripting, so help is appreciated

-Alex

Comment: possible duplicate of [redirect COPY of stdout to log file from within bash script itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131/redirect-copy-of-stdout-to-log-file-from-within-bash-script-itself) -- sorry for the shameless advertising, but I didn't want to copy my answer over. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> filename=uname -a
> filename="$filename" date
>
> 2>&1 | tee $filename".txt"
> ```
>
> ...
>   If you look at the code I posted above
>   I'm trying to dynamically name the log
>   and use tee to print to both the
>   console and the command line.

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
filename="$(uname -n)-$(date +%F).txt"
{
  dostuff
  domorestuff
} 2>&1 | tee "$filename"
```

Answer (score 1):

its wrong because you are not assigning your variables properly. Assuming `date` is GNU date, and not some "date" function you created. you might be looking for. Use `$()` syntax to execute commands and put to variable.

```
filename="$(uname -a)$(date)"
```

By the way, are you sure you want to use `uname -a` for filename ? you might also want to consider formatting your date like `date +%Y%m%d-%H%m%s` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should just print everything to console with echo. Then you can redirect that to a log. For example:

```
# my_file.sh
echo "Doing stuff"
# Do stuff

# Invocation:
my_file.sh > my_log.log
```

This gives you the most flexibility and elegance.

You can also write to log directly from script, like:

```
# my_file.sh
echo "Doing stuff" > my_log.log
# Do stuff
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. If you look at the code I posted above I'm trying to dynamically name the log and use tee to print to both the console and the command line.