# redirect all output in a bash script when using set -x

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have a bash script that has `set -x` in it. Is it possible to redirect the debug prints of this script and all its output to a file? Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
(some magic command here...) > /tmp/mylog
echo "test"
```

and get the

```
+ echo test
test
```

output in /tmp/mylog, not in stdout.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe).  It's not a duplicate, but I believe this should answer your question.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is what I've just googled and I remember myself using this some time ago...

Use exec to redirect both standard output and standard error of all commands in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
logfile=$$.log
exec > $logfile 2>&1
```

For more redirection magic check out [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide - I/O Redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

If you also want to see the output and debug on the terminal in *addition* to in the log file, see [redirect COPY of stdout to log file from within bash script itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131/redirect-copy-of-stdout-to-log-file-from-within-bash-script-itself).

If you want to handle the destination of the `set -x` trace output independently of normal `STDOUT` and `STDERR`, see [bash storing the output of set -x to log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610862/bash-storing-the-output-of-set-x-to-log-file).

Comment: Interesting. How could I use this method to both capture errors (stdout 2) into a logfile AND return them to stdout 2; so cron could properly email error alerts?

Comment: @JoeyT, see if this works for you: backup the STDOUT before setting up logfile with `exec 3<&1`, then add in these two lines at the end: `exec 1<&3 3<&-` and `cat $$.log` -- this should restore STDOUT and close fd 3 to cleanup. Based on the original `tldp` reference and this [http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ioredirintro.html](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ioredirintro.html)

Comment: @JoeyT I've edited the answer and added two more helpful links; the first one should be enough to explain how you can do this.

Answer (score 18):

the `-x` output goes to stderr, so to log it do:

```
set -x
exec 2>/tmp/mylog
```

Answer (score 3):

To redirect **stderr** and **stdout**:

```
exec &>> $LOG_FILE_NAME
```

If you want to append to file. To overwrite file:

```
exec &> $LOG_FILE_NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the script was being called multiple times from elsewhere, and I wasn't seeing everything, so I did an append instead, and it worked:

```
exec 1>>FILENAME 2>&1
set -x
```

To avoid confusion, be sure to delete FILENAME before each run.