# Specify one output file and another error file for the whole shell script?

Tags: shell

I wish to have one file `output.txt` to hold all the outputs of my shell script. Similarly, a `error.txt` file to hold all the errors of my shell script.

I understand that technically, I can achieve this by manually appending `>>output.txt` to **every** line that prints out something. However, I feel that very ugly. I vaguely remember something like

```
#!/bin/sh
#$ -o ./output.txt
#$ -e ./error.txt

echo Hello World!
```

may work. However, it is somehow not working when I try it out.

So, how can I specify one output file that automatically absorbs all the outputs?

## Update

This question may seem like a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229385/redirect-all-output-in-a-bash-script-when-using-set-x). Yet, one difference is that I also wish to separate outputs and errors into two separate files.

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11229385/redirect-all-output-in-a-bash-script-when-using-set-x `exec > your_log_file 2>&1` You could also run the script like this: `./your_script.sh > output`

Comment: @fedorqui This works perfectly! However, it would be even better if I could separate outputs and errors into two files. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in [redirect all output in a bash script when using set -x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11229385/1983854), you can use this approach:

```
exec > log_file 2>&1
```

If you want to specify different files for stdin and stderr, do:

```
exec 2> log_error 1> log_output
```

#### Test

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 2> error 1> mylog
echo "hello this is this"
ls alsdjflask
```

and we get...

```
$ ./a
$ cat mylog 
hello this is this
$ cat error 
ls: cannot access alsdjflask: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks a lot for the quick and sweet solution!

Comment: You are welcome :) I didn't know about it, so both of us learnt a nice thing today.