# bash storing the output of set -x to log file

Tags: bash, debugging, output, non-interactive

I have a simple download script and I use `set -x` which works great;
I can see each step it performs, and I can identify errors in the script
or in the download:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
#short_date=$(/bin/date +%m%d%y)
short_date=$(/bin/date -d "8 day ago" +%m%d%y)
#long_date=$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d)
long_date=$(/bin/date -d "8 day ago" +%Y%m%d)
scp -v -P 1332 -i /home/casper/.ssh/id_rsa_BANK friendly@192.168.1.10:/home/friendly/transfer/out/EXCHANGE_$short_date.csv /local/casper3/dailymetrics/BANK_$long_date.csv
```

I would like to automate this job. Is there a way I could save the `set -x` output to a log file?  Maybe to one log file - or a different log file for each day. I don't know what would work best.

Below is sample `set -x` output from the above script.

```
++ /bin/date +%m%d%y
+ short_date=102814
++ /bin/date +%Y%m%d
+ long_date=20141028
+ scp -v -P 1332 -i /home/casper/.ssh/id_rsa_BANK friendly@192.168.1.10:/home/friendly/transfer/out/EXCHANGE_102814.csv /local/casper3/dailymetrics/BANK_20141028.csv
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host 192.168.1.10, user friendly, command scp -v -f /home/friendly/transfer/out/EXCHANGE_102814.csv
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/casper/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.10 [192.168.1.10] port 7777.
debug1: Connection established.
```

Comment: Which version? With bash 4 you can do this without redirecting all of stderr; with old versions, it's all the same stream.

Comment: By the way, you might consider something like `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+'` to log the file and line for each command.

Comment: Take a look at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155553/74329

Answer (score 20):

Assuming bash 4, `BASH_XTRACEFD` can be set to override the file descriptor (by default 2, stderr) to which `set -x` output is written:

```
short_date=$(/bin/date +%m%d%y)
exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}>>"$short_date".log
set -x
```

If running bash 4.0 rather than 4.1 or newer, you have BASH_XTRACEFD but not automatic file descriptor allocation, meaning you'll need to assign one yourself; in the below example, I'm picking file descriptor 100:

```
short_date=$(/bin/date +%m%d%y)
exec 100>>"$short_date".log
BASH_XTRACEFD=100
set -x
```

For older releases, your only choice is to redirect all of stderr, rather than only the xtrace stream:

```
short_date=$(/bin/date +%m%d%y)
exec 2>>"$short_date.log"
set -x
```

Comment: Should that be `${BASH_XTRACEFD}` or is there a peculiar feature I need to read about?

Comment: @Alfe, yes, there's a feature at play here -- the automatic file descriptor allocation previously mentioned. Quoting from the redirection section of the bash manual: "Each redirection that may be preceded by a file descriptor number may instead be preceded by a word of the form {varname}. In this case, for each redirection operator except >&- and <&-, the shell will allocate a file descriptor greater than 10 and assign it to {varname}. If >&- or <&- is preceded by {varname}, the value of varname defines the file descriptor to close."

Comment: It's also possible to use `tee` to keep a copy on `STDERR`, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131/redirect-copy-of-stdout-to-log-file-from-within-bash-script-itself.

Comment: @AdamSpiers, you lose sync between the copy going through tee and the content written directly if you log the traced output to different sinks even if later rejoining it to stderr; thus, using `exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}> >(tee xtrace.log >&2)` or any equivalent is not something I'd advise. (If you mean to log *all* stderr output -- both from xtrace and otherwise -- to both a file and console, you don't have that problem). Anyhow, the OP here is asking about logging only xtrace, which is why that's the question I answered.

Comment: @AdamSpiers, ...POSIX guarantees ordering between writes only if they're to copies of the same FD; as soon as you redirect one but not the other, things get messy. You have the same problem if you try to log stdout and stderr to two different files.

Comment: (err, log stdout and stderr to two different files, *and also* to a combined output file or the console).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks - yes, I'm aware the OP didn't ask for this, which is why I added it as a comment rather than a new answer. I'm also aware of ordering challenges, e.g. see the end of [my answer to the question I linked to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11886837/179332). A link to that exact POSIX clause would be helpful though; to me it seems that the ordering difficulties are related to the use of asynchronous coprocesses (which necessitate the use of different FDs).

Comment: Above was an oversimplification -- there are certainly cases defined by POSIX where it's safe to have two entirely separate handles on the same file appending concurrently (albeit only if `O_APPEND` is in use, the content being written is in chunks that each fit within a single `write()` call, and one doesn't otherwise get partial/interrupted writes).

Comment: @AdamSpiers, ...that said, timestamp-based reassembly is necessarily fragile on account of the issues you've already acknowledged; given a requirement for perfect reconstruction, I'd probably use something like [sysdig](http://sysdig.org/) to record the actual syscalls (with much lower overhead than `strace`, and a pcap-derived storage format and toolchain surrounding same that lends itself to scripting.).

Comment: Is `>>` required? Or can I use `exec 100> ...` instead?

Comment: That's all a matter of whether you want to truncate.