# Where does `set -x` cause bash to print to?

Tags: bash

If I `set -x` in my bash session ( v4.1.2(2) - CentOS 6.10), I get :

```
$ ls /root
+ ls --color=auto /root
ls: cannot open directory /root: Permission denied
```

Great, it echo's the command I ran and prints out the terminal. This is expected. Now if I redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to the another file.

```
$ ls /root  &> stuff.txt
+ ls --color=auto /root
```

It still prints the command to the terminal.

**QUESTION**

Where is `set -x` having bash print to if it isn't `stderr` or `stdout`?

Comment: Looks like "to the console" :)

Comment: Relevant? https://serverfault.com/questions/296991/send-bash-x-output-to-logfile-without-interupting-standard-output/579078#579078

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273665/what-does-set-x-do

Comment: This should help (but not a dupe) https://stackoverflow.com/q/11229385/2988730

Comment: This actually answers the question (mostly), but also not a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26610862/2988730

Comment: @irritable_phd_syndrom : To stderr.

Comment: You can verify it if you have a script x.sh and you do a `bash -x x.sh 2>/dev/null`. You will see that no trace is displayed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `set -x` command prints tracing information to `stderr`.

When you run this command...

```
ls /root  &> stuff.txt
```

You're only redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` for the `ls` command. You're not changing either for your *current* shell, which is where you have run `set -x`.

---

As Mad Physicist points out, the technical answer is "it logs to `BASH_XTRACEFD`", which defaults to `stderr`. You can redirect trace logging for the current shell to another file by doing something like:

```
# open a new file descriptor for logging
exec 4> trace.log

# redirect trace logs to fd 4
BASH_XTRACEFD=4

# enable tracing
set -x
```

Comment: Technically, it prints to whatever `BASH_XTRACEFD` is set to.

Answer (score 3):

When you execute a command, you can redirect the standard output (known as `/dev/stdout`) of the command directly to the file. Also if the command generates error-output (generally send to `/dev/stderr`) you can also redirect it to a file as:

```
$ command > /path/to/output.txt 2> /path/to/error.txt
```

When you execute the command `set -x`, you ask it to generate a *trace* of the commands being executed. It does this by sending messages to `/dev/stderr`. In contrast to a normal command, you cannot easily redirect this in a similar way as with a normal command. This is because `bash` executes the script and at the same time generates the trace to `/dev/stderr`. So if you would like to catch the trace, you would have to redirect the error output of `bash` directly. This can be done by the command

```
 exec 2> /path/to/trace.txt
```

**note:** this will at the same time also contain all the error output of any command executed in the script.

**Examples:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
command
```

This sends all output and error output to the terminal

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
command 2> /path/to/command.err
```

This sends the output of `command` and the trace of bash to the terminal but catches the error output of `command` in a file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
exec 2> /path/to/trace.err
command 2> /path/to/command.err
```

This sends the output of `command` to the terminal, the error output of `command` to a file, and the trace of the script to `/path/to/trace.err`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
exec 2> /path/to/trace_and_command.err
command
```

This sends the output of `command` to the terminal, the trace and the error of `command` to a file.