# What does minus mean in "exec 3>&-" and how do I use it?

Tags: bash, redirect, terminal, stdout, sh

I often have trouble figuring out certain language constructs because they won't register when googling or duckduckgoing them. With a bit of experimenting, it's often simple to figure it out, but I don't get this one.

I often see stuff like `2>&1` or `3>&-` in bash scripts. I know this is some kind of redirection. 1 is stdout and 2 is stderror. 3 is probably custom. But what is the minus?

Also, I have a script whose output I want to log, but also want to see on screen. I use `exec > >(tee $LOGFILE); exec 2>&1` for that. It works. But sometimes when I bashtrap this script, I cannot type at the prompt anymore. Output is hidden after `Ctrl+C`. Can I use a custom channel and the minus sign to fix this, or is it unrelated?

Comment: You've got two accurate answers.  The document [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) also covers the use of these notations and explains why the sea shells should be left on the sea shore and not used for writing scripts.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. `2>&1` means that stderr is redirected to stdout
2. `3>&-` means that file descriptor 3, opened for writing(same as stdout), is closed.

You can see more examples of redirection [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/x13082.html)

3. As for questions number 3, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131/redirect-copy-of-stdout-to-log-file-from-within-bash-script-itself) is a good link.

Answer (score 4):

The `3>&-` close the file descriptor number 3 (it probably has been opened before with `3>filename`).

The `2>&1` redirect the output of file descriptor 2 (stderr) to the same destination as file descriptor 1 (stdout). This dies call `dup2()` syscall.

For more information about redirecting file descriptor please consult the bash manpages (`man bash). They are dense but great.

For your script, I would do it like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -z $recursive_call ]]; then
  recursive_call=1
  export recursive_call
  "$0" "$@" | tee filename
  exit
fi
# rest of the script goes there
```

It lose the exit code from the script though. There is a way in bash to get it I guess but I can't remember it now.