# Redirect a COPY of stdout to different log files multiple times from within same bash script

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, exec, tee

Following line works well when we want to redirect the stdout to a file, and also get printed on stdout.

```
exec > >(tee logfile-1.txt)
```

However, if we wish to later redirect the stdout to another file, say,

```
exec > >(tee logfile-2.txt)
```

the issue faced is that the output still keeps getting redirected to the first file (logfile-1.txt) along with the second file (logfile-2.txt).

Is there a way that the same bash script contains both the statement, and the output be exclusive to each of the files corresponding to the order of execution of these commands?

Note:
This question is in extension to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3403786/2052755) for the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131/redirect-copy-of-stdout-to-log-file-from-within-bash-script-itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do

```
{
    command1
    command2
} | tee logfile-1.txt

{
    command3
    command4
} | tee logfile-2.txt
```

Alternatively, backup the original filedescriptor, first:

```
exec 6<&1
exec > >(tee log1)
echo 1
echo 2
exec 1<&6 6<&-
exec > >(tee log2)
echo 3
echo 4
```

See http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/x13082.html for many more advanced uses of `exec`