# Output shell script to log file

Tags: unix, logging

I have a scheduled unix script that I want to log the output of. I am unable to edit the cron file due to the user interface restrictions, and I am unable to add >> logfile to the command. Is there something I can add within the script itself to send the output to a log?

```
{

printf poo

 #Do not change
PRINTF=/usr/bin/printf
MSMTP=/usr/local/bin/msmtp
MSMTPCONF=/var/etc/msmtp.conf

 #Can be changed
FROM="nas4free@usinfosec.com"
TO="dpatino@usinfosec.com"
MDIR="CaseData"
SUBJECT="$MDIR Backup Report"


} > /mnt/support/logs/$SUBJECT.log
#BODY="$(cat /mnt/support/logs/test.log)"
#$PRINTF "From:$FROM\nTo:$TO\nSubject:$SUBJECT\n\n$BODY" | $MSMTP --file=$MSMTPCONF -t
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
#!/bin/bash
exec > /tmp/myLog.log 2>&1
set -x
```

The log shows:

```
+ echo 'Hello World!'
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to wrap your script in braces and redirect the output as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
# script contents here
echo running script
} > logfile
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked until I added a variable in the logfile name. I've added my code to the question.

Comment: move the `SUBJECT` variable assignment outside the braces.

Comment: @dogbane with this `>> logfile` I can append to the logfile, is it possible to "append to the top" in the logfile? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Append following line in starting of your script

```
log_file_path="/tmp/output.log"
log() { while IFS='' read -r line; do echo "$line" >> "$log_file_path"; done; };
exec > >(tee >(log)) 2>&1
```

Your script with modification

```
PRINTF=/usr/bin/printf
MSMTP=/usr/local/bin/msmtp
MSMTPCONF=/var/etc/msmtp.conf
FROM="nas4free@usinfosec.com"
TO="dpatino@usinfosec.com"
MDIR="CaseData"
SUBJECT="$MDIR Backup Report"

{

printf poo  


} > /mnt/support/logs/$SUBJECT.log
#BODY="$(cat /mnt/support/logs/test.log)"
#$PRINTF "From:$FROM\nTo:$TO\nSubject:$SUBJECT\n\n$BODY" | $MSMTP --file=$MSMTPCONF -t
```

Comment: I don't really understand what that's doing. I put that at the top of the script?

Comment: @DarylPatino Find better explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131/redirect-copy-of-stdout-to-log-file-from-within-bash-script-itself.

Comment: Thanks, that's for bash. I need something for sh.

Comment: @DarylPatino Please see updated answer. In your code you need to move variable out. So you can use variable in that scope.