# Continuously write output of console to a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to continuously write output of console to a file, output may come from two or more programs. By continuously I mean I should be able to view all the stdout of any program running on that machine in that file once I run required command or code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [redirect COPY of stdout to log file from within bash script itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131/redirect-copy-of-stdout-to-log-file-from-within-bash-script-itself)

Comment: Sorry for the self-promotion of my own accepted answer, but the linked question is very popular question on SO, and if there's anything to add, it should go there.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you want? @Rahul already demonstrated how easy it is to redirect output from a single program, but if you want to redirect *all* commands in *all* shells, that's a completely different problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just redirect the `stdout` to that file like

```
command > file_name
```

Comment: If you want to see the output *and* log it, you can use `command | tee > file_name`.

Comment: @l0b0, Post this as an answer, output redirection is an approach, basically redirection is bypassing the stdout, but `tee` can overcome and should be ideal for any such operation

Answer (score 1):

You can start your bash script by the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 2> /tmp/outfile.log  # send stderr from your script to a log file
exec 1>&2                      # send stdout to the same log file
set -x
# the rest of your code ...
```

Comment: What does "set -x" do?