# Grep-ing while keeping first line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, pipe

I am trying to understand this peculiar behavior. Basically, I'm trying to grep an output of a command while still keeping the first line/header.  Thanks for the help in advance.

### Success Case

```
ps -ef | { head -1; grep bash; }
```

Output:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
username  1008     1  0 Jan21 tty1     00:00:00 -bash
username  1173  1008  0 Jan21 tty1     00:00:00 -bash
```

### Failed Case

```
 ls -tlrh / | { head -1; grep tmp; }
```

Output:

```
total 100K
```

(i.e.: it ignores the `/tmp` folder)

Comment: so far the two answers solved the problem, but I think OP wanted to understand why one case was success and the other one failed. The two answers cannot explain it. I edited the question by adding several tags. I do group command then pipe to another cmd, but not tested to pipe to command group. Interesting question +1 want to know the reason. BTW, if you check the 2nd failed case `echo $?` the return value is `1`, but I cannot see any error msg by adding `2>&1` to all commands...

Comment: I can't replicate this on my system... Is there possibly some sort of permissions issue preventing a non-root user from reading `/` or something?

Comment: @Kent. Thanks for the edit and yes, I would like to understand the reason behind it. I noticed it's not limited to these 2 commands only. I used check_mk monitoring and the 'cmk -D' ouput gave the success result as well.

Answer (score 6):

@Jotne's answer is better, but sometimes you can use `grep -E` if you know something in the first line, then you can search for that OR the other thing you want like this with the pipe symbol to express the alternation:

```
ps -ef | grep -E "UID|bash"
```

**Output**

```
UID   PID  PPID   C STIME   TTY           TIME CMD
502   510   509   0  8:01am ttys000    0:00.08 -bash
502 48806   510   0 10:18am ttys000    0:00.00 grep -E UID|bash
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yah, this is the way that I've been using but I dont really like it because I need to look into the output first just to get the line.

Comment: This is actually nice for casual use. Most times you want something fast and not type too much

Answer (score 4):

Try use `awk`, eks:

```
ls -tlrh / | awk 'NR==1 || /tmp/'
```

This will print line number `1` or lines with `tmp`

`NR==1;`  print line number `1`
`/tmp/` print all lines that contains `tmp`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Its very elegant and I like it. However, I cannot mark it as answer since it doesnt explain the reason for the peculiar behaviour.

Comment: The first line will be printed twice if it matches the regex. Combine the conditions using OR instead of using two awk commands: `awk 'NR==1 || /tmp/'`

Answer (score 1):

The reason this does not work, is that the first of the two processes (head -n1) reads more than it outputs. It eats up the output of ls and leaves nothing for the grep process; ps creates its output linewise.

The correct way to solve this would be to duplicate STDOUT for every process that needs it, as described here

[redirect COPY of stdout to log file from within bash script itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131/redirect-copy-of-stdout-to-log-file-from-within-bash-script-itself)

However here it would suffice to simply feed the reading scripts line by line to avoid any buffering issues:

```
ls -ltrh / | while { read a; } do echo $a; done | { head -n 1; grep tmp; }
```

However, this means that grep can not see the line(s), head has consumed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried to run the command but I still get the same output as the original command I ran. Or, am I missing something?

Comment: This worked for me; however if it does not for you, you should stick to the canonical solution mentioned (dupping stdout). This would be the one outlined below by Zoltán Nagy - tee >(command >&3) duplicates the output to the first command, sending this commands output to fd 3, then grep uses stdin and in the end the output of fd 3 is redirected to stdout.

Comment: I do not see a reason why would the inserted script `while read ...` change the input buffering of `head` to line buffering. The inserted script can certainly process multiple lines and send them to `stdout` together in a single `write()` call.

Answer (score 0):

well.. this works to...but just for noting a very convoluted solution

`(ps aux | tee >(head -n1 >&3 ) | grep bio >&3 ) 3>&1`

this is not as nice as i wanted it to be, fd3 usage makes it weird

note: it might even theorecally possible that grep output preceeds the header

Comment: Great idea allowing to use real `grep` or any other filter! --- Unfortunately the implementation does not work. When `head` stops reading (soon after first line), `tee` terminates and rest of the output is not processed. Also the first line can show twice if it matches in `grep`. This fixes the problems: `(ps aux | tee >(head -n1 >&3 ; cat >/dev/null) | tail -n+2 | grep bio >&3 ) 3>&1` --- Not sure how to nicely fix possible grep output preceding head output. To make the chance negligible grep in a sub-shell can be preceded by `sleep .1` and/or run with a lower priority: `nice grep bio`.

Comment: I made an answer by improving your idea (using `awk`) here: [How to grep a specific line _and_ the first line of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/701574/19702)

Answer (score 0):

pure sed solution ;)

`ps aux|sed '1p;/kwork/p;d'`