# Unix: Is it possible to copy error output to a file while still displaying all output?

Tags: bash, unix

I've seen things like

`command > out.txt`

Sometimes appended with

```
2&1
```

But these seem to divert all output or all error streams instead of both displaying and copying the output into the file, which is what I'm trying to do. Do I have any options?

Comment: you want to use `tee`

Comment: see [how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout)

Comment: Can be done from [within a script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131) as well.

Comment: This question is definitely not a duplicate of 418896. This question asks how to separate out stderr into its own file while simultaneously displaying all output on the screen, which is something that the linked "dupe" does not cover; it does not mention the &3 trick. A more related question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout

Answer (score 6):

If you can have stdout and stderr into the file

```
command 2>&1 | tee -a log
```

Else you swap stdout and stderr using `3`

```
{ command | tee stdout.log; } 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee stderr.log
```

Comment: Clever! I didn't know one could use &3. The solution to this problem has eluded me for years.