# Can i create log file during/after building a container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Normally it is possible to create log file of running container but i want create a log file of a build container is it possible.If yes, then how to create log file?

Answer (score 1):

The command you're looking for is

`( sudo docker build -t abc ) | tee build.log`

as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3173242/1309035). This will show the progress of the build on your console and also log it into `build.log`.

Note: You cannot log what happens *in* an image. The image is like a blueprint. You can monitor how the blueprint is made, but then it stops. When you build something from that blueprint (e.g. a container), you monitor the new item.

Comment: I  am not getting it,can you please give the command to create a log file of following image.If i am building an application image using the command:     sudo docker build -t abc . where abc is by application image.