# Redirect output to a file AND console

Tags: bash

Currently I have a script where I want all output to be redirected to both a file and the console.

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /mnt/ybdata/ybvwconf.log 
{
  ... [Do some script code here]
} 2>&1 | tee -a /mnt/ybdata/ybvwconf.log
```

Above, you can see my current code, which works perfectly fine. It prints all the output to the console as well as piping it to the ybvwconf.log file. However, I was looking for a way to eliminate the curly brackets. Something along the lines of this:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /mnt/ybdata/ybvwconf.log
exec 2>&1 | tee -a /mnt/ybdata/ybvwconf.log

... [Do some script code here]
```

I have tried this approach and sadly it does not work. I don't get any errors but no content appears in my log file. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to eliminate the curly brackets?

Comment: You don't need to `touch` first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect COPY of stdout to log file from within bash script itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131/redirect-copy-of-stdout-to-log-file-from-within-bash-script-itself)

Answer (score 1):

You can place this at top of your script to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file and show them on terminal as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec &> >(tee /mnt/ybdata/ybvwconf.log; exit)

# your script code goes here
```

Comment: This does not seem to work as intended when I run it. It gives an error:

`No such file or directory/dev/fd/62`

Comment: Is `/mnt/ybdata/` a valid and accessible directory for your script? Try this to test: `exec &> >(tee /tmp/ybvwconf.log; exit)`

Comment: Yep it is. I tried with `/tmp/ybvwconf.log` as well and I am getting the same error at the start of the script.

Comment: You have some strange permission issue because this is working fine in my bash and creates `/tmp/ybvwconf.log` every time I run this script.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I'll poke around a bit and see if I can find out why. Might be something to do with the VM I am running the script on.