# How to put stdout file descriptor in a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, file-descriptor

I am using `echo var >> "${log_file}" 2>&1` to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to a file path stored in the `${log_file}`. But when the variable is empty, I would like to send `stdout` and `stderr` to their default/standard locations.

For example, if the variable `${log_file}` is empty, the output should not go to a file, but to `stdout`. How I should set the `${log_file}` variable value to make it output to `stdout`?

I tried setting to `&1` (the `stdout` file descriptor)

```shell
if [[ -z "${log_file}" ]]; then
    log_file=&1
fi

echo var >> "${log_file}" 2>&1
```

But it did not work and bash threw this error:

```
No such file or directory
1: command not found
```

Comment: On a more general approach to logging bash output, you might want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173131). (Doesn't require to redirect each command's output individually.)

Comment: How about using `exec` to create the file descriptor? Can't you redirect in the `if ... else` branch directly?

Comment: `>>&1` is a redirection operator that has to be parsed *before* parameter expansion happens. There isn't really a clean, short way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two fundamentally different operations based on the value of the variable:

1. Redirection *both* stderr and stdout to the named file
2. Don't redirect either.

There's no syntax to handle this dichotomy. I would recommend the following:

1. Wrap the command whose output you might want to redirection in a function.

   ```
   func () {
       echo var
   }
   ```
2. Use an `if` statement to call that function with and without redirection, as necessary.

   ```
   if [ -n "$log_file" ]; then
       func >> "$log_file" 2>&1
   else
       func
   fi
   ```

Another approach is to define `func` conditionally, attaching the redirection directly to the function.

```
if [ -n "$log_file" ]; then
    func () {
        echo var
    } >> "$log_file" 2>&1
else
    func () { 
        echo var
    }
fi

func
```