# How to copy both stdout and stderr to a file with timestamp from within a bash script?

Tags: bash

I've used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27346142/1257145), which only copies stdout to file:

```
$ cat /etc/dehydrated/syncNexusCertificatesHook.sh 
#!/bin/bash -ex

exec &> >(ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' | tee -a /var/log/dehydrated.log >&2 )
...
```

When running the script, there was a `perl: warning: Setting locale failed.` printed to the terminal, but not to the log file.

I want to have all output from the script printed with a timestamp printed to the console as well as saved to the log file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can redirect `ts` stderr to the logfile too

Comment: use `2>&1` instead of  `&>`

Comment: Alongside tou want both in log file, do you want anything to the console?

Comment: @thanasisp both in log file and to the console

Comment: @Digvijay S do I need to replace the >&2 in the end as well?

Comment: In the console, do you want timestamps with the output or the timestamps are only  for the log file?

Comment: Timestamps should also be in the console.

Comment: Can you try `|&` instead of `|` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect both stdout and stderr of a command to a sequence of commands, and finally to both the console and a file, you can do it with this syntax

```sh
command |& ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' | tee file
```

which is the synonym of this

```sh
command 2>&1 | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' | tee file
```

or redirecting both streams to a process substitution

```sh
command &> >(ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' | tee file)
```

or redirecting the output and then make the stderr a copy of stdout

```sh
command > >(ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' | tee file) 2>&1
```